# char written to a char* array mutates somehow

Tags: c, char, buffer

This should be a simple function (it counts the number of unique chars in a string), but I'm getting a weird issue. Note that my code use expects only ASCII letters a-z, and A-Z.

```
int unique_chars(char* my_str) {
//printf("starting unique_chars\n");
  char seen_buffer[52]; // max 52 letters a-z & A-Z
  int seen_count = 1; // not ever expecting my_str to be NULL 
  int i, j;
  char next;
//printf("first char is %c\n", my_str[0]);
  seen_buffer[0] = my_str[0]; // first char must be unique

  for (i=1; i<strlen(my_str); i++) { // walk along the rest of my_str
    next = my_str[i];

    if (next >= 97) {
      next = next - 32; // the next char will always be capital, for convenience
    }

    for (j=0; j<seen_count; j++) { // compare next to all the unique chars seen before
//printf("current char is %c, checking against %c\n", next, seen_buffer[j]);
      if ((next==seen_buffer[j]) || (next+32==seen_buffer[j])) {
//printf("breaking\n");
        break; // jump to the next char in my_str if we find a match
      }
      if (j==seen_count-1) { // at this point, we're sure that next hasn't been seen yet
//printf("new unique char is %c\n", next);
        seen_count++;
        seen_buffer[seen_count] = next;
//printf("new char val is %c, should be %c\n", seen_buffer[seen_count], next);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return seen_count;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  char* to_encode = argv[1];
  printf("unique chars: %d\n", unique_chars(to_encode));
}
```

When I call with certain strings, I get incorrect results. For example, try:

```
./a.out gghhiijj
```

which yields (with the printf's uncommented):

```
starting unique_chars
first char is g
current char is G, checking against g
breaking
current char is H, checking against g
new unique char is H
new char val is H, should be H
current char is H, checking against g
current char is H, checking against 
new unique char is H
new char val is H, should be H
current char is I, checking against g
current char is I, checking against 
current char is I, checking against H
new unique char is I
new char val is I, should be I
current char is I, checking against g
current char is I, checking against 
current char is I, checking against H
current char is I, checking against H
new unique char is I
new char val is I, should be I
current char is J, checking against g
current char is J, checking against 
current char is J, checking against H
current char is J, checking against H
current char is J, checking against I
new unique char is J
new char val is J, should be J
current char is J, checking against g
current char is J, checking against 
current char is J, checking against H
current char is J, checking against H
current char is J, checking against I
current char is J, checking against I
new unique char is J
new char val is J, should be J
```

So I keep getting duplicates in my seen_buffer because some whitespace char is stored there instead of the alphabetical char that should be there! Yet when I do the comparison right after writing to the seen_buffer (i.e. new char val is %c, should be %c\n), the correct char is shown!

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `if (next >= 97) {` // What is the value of 'a' in the EBCDIC character set? Research it. What is the point of C code, if not to be portable? Research the history of C. Why aren't you using `'a'` in place of 97?

Comment: Suppose you want to check if a character is lowercase: `if (islower((unsigned char) next)) { ... }`, now suppose you want to convert that lowercase char to an uppercase char: `next = islower((unsigned char) next) ? toupper((unsigned char) next) : next;` Let your compiler do the optimisations for you, because it's smart enough to perform dead code elimination and tail-call optimisation.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Didn't know that isLower existed -- very helpful!

Comment: `islower` is in `<ctype.h>`, as is `toupper`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an off-by-one error here:

```
    seen_count++;
    seen_buffer[seen_count] = next;
```

The first char goes in `seen_buffer[0]` and `seen_count` is set to 1.  Which means that the *next* new character goes in `seen_buffer[2]` after `seen_count` is incremented to 2.  Nothing ever goes in `seen_buffer[1]` (that's the blank character you keep seeing in your printfs), and when checking a character against the `seen_buffer`, you never check against the last character you just put in.

Swap these lines and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking if the value entered is between A to Z and a to z

Also your current code can have a buffer overflow at char seen_buffer[52] so add bounds check in the code

I think your code can be much straightforward

Here is a simple algorithm for you

```
 unsigned int returnUniqueChar (const char *input)
 {
     int count[52] = {0}; // initialize all the memory with zero
     int unique = 0;

     while (*input != '\0')
     {
          if ( (input >= 'A' && input <= 'Z') 
          {
                count[input -'A']++;
          }

           else if (input >= 'a' && input <= 'z')
          {
              count[input -'a'+ 26]++;
          }
          input++;
     }

     for (int i = 0; i < 56 && (count[i] == 1) ; i++ )
            unique++;

    return unique;

 }
```

Comment: Thanks! At the top of my question, I actually mention that I only expect inputs containing the chars a-z and A-Z (would take a while to explain why, but this is the only use case I have to worry about), so the verification is omitted. Also, because of this, there should be no worry about buffer overflow: since there are 52 chars from a,...,z,A,...,Z, any string containing that alphabet gives a maximal number of seen_buffer (and is guaranteed to fit in the buffer).

I do like your algorithm a lot better, though I'm still curious about what's wrong with mine. Thanks for the work-around though!

Comment: well i always feel that an api must be hard to break . In your case, people might not follow the restriction and end up passing invalid character. a simple example would be passing the input read from a stdinput.in those cases the input would contain \n or \r and it would break your code

Comment: can you add comments in your code to explain us your what you are trying to do at each line. its not straight forward to me atleast.

Comment: Where does the C standard mention that 'A' .. 'Z' are contiguously incremental in value? Have a look at EBCDIC, and think about the purpose of functions such as "islower" and "toupper".